# Show the documentation for the current commandline parameters

Tags: autocomplete, fish

When using `fish` I often struggle where I hit tab to open up the command line completion. But then when I type the first letter of the completion the menu closes. Can I keep it open and have it select / reduce the options so that I don't need to delete the letter, hit tab again, etc to view what my letter stood for?

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the completions search feature, allowing you to reduce the options. It looks like so:

[image: fish-shell completion search field]

You can open the search field when the completion pager is already shown via Control-S. Alternatively you can trigger tab completion with the search field focused via shift-tab. These keys can be changed using [bind](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html) if you prefer.